# How to dispay Input from non-parent component using Angular?

Tags: angular

I have a simple project,  where I'm trying to learn Angular. Here is a repo https://github.com/paslavskyi9roman/Freecher

There are 2 components: **Post** - where all the posts are displayed (see screenshot [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuLd0.png)), and **Create-Post** (see screenshot [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUOkp.png)), on a separate route, where you can fill the input and send the data so entered data will be displayed on a Post component.

I've tried to implement the `@input @output` approach, but apparently, it's Parent/Child components only.

[Post (main screen)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuLd0.png)

[Create Post page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUOkp.png)

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: do you mean how to display/update posts once a create post is completed?

Comment: There is many ways. One would be to use Angular service that would need to be embedded to both components and can communicate state. For example via observable.

Comment: @depperm yes sir. Once I pressed the "Create Post" button, I would like to update the main screen, with a new post on top of the page

Comment: I would suggest looking at polling or SSE (server side event) for posts, that way when anyone creates a post (not just you) the posts screen will update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a subject to broadcast the values . Then subscribe to the subject in the other component.

in your file you want to send the values from:

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

const broadcaster = new Subject()
export const $broadcaster = broadcaster.asObservable()


function sendMessage(message: any) {
  broadcaster.next(message)
}
```

in the component you want to use it in:

```
import { $broadcaster } from 'path to first file here';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  brodcastValue //will be null on init, once the subscription fires will give you whatever you called next on in the other file
  title = 'devInterface';

  ngOnInit() {
    $broadcaster.subscribe(val => this.brodcastValue = val)
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems like I should learn RxJS beforehand 